# What is the role of し after the noun?

Tags: conjugations, nouns, renyōkei

I can't understand the role of し after 留学 in the sentence:

> 来年、日本に留学**し**に行くと決めた。

I heard that it is supposed to be a conjugated form of する, but I don't know a conjugation ending in just し. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is し used as a verb in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41324/how-is-%e3%81%97-used-as-a-verb-in-this-sentence)

Comment: In the end it is about the same problem, yes. But in your example I would have probably noticed it myself, as し was followed by を. In this context - at least for me - it wasn't that obvious that it was the stem of する.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

しに行くis a way to express "go **with the purpose of doing** (something)".

The し is the Continuative Form (連用形) of する - you will probably recognize it as the base part of します. All verbs have a continuative form. For example, 話す would be 話し, 食べる would be 食べ, etc. Basically it's the part that comes before ます.

When you have the construction:
`Verb 1 (continuative form) + に + Verb 2`, it means "to do Verb 2 with the purpose of carrying out Verb 1".

So in your example sentence,  留学しに行く means "go (Verb 2 行く) with the purpose of studying abroad (Verb 1 留学する)".

But it doesn't always have to be し, as that is only the case with する. Another example phrase would be 先生に聞きに行く. This time 聞く is in the continuative form 聞き. So the phrase is translated literally as "go to the teacher with the purpose of asking something". A more natural translation would be "to go ask the teacher". You might also recognize the phrase 見に行く (to go see something). This is also the same construction `Verb 1 continuative form + に + Verb 2.`

Comment: Wow!  I didn't expect such a detailed answer. Now I get it. I just wasn't too familiar with the concept of [Verb in continuative stem + に  + verb]. Great answer! Thank you a lot!

Comment: @ElGringo Glad to be of help.