# The meaning of 「し」in this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 「彼が戦慄**し**つぶやいた」

[What is the role of し after the noun?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/62447/what-is-the-role-of-%e3%81%97-after-the-noun)

I already looked up the answer to this question. The 「**し**」is explained as ""to do Verb 2 with the purpose of carrying out Verb 1" in construction that also include 「**に**」. Although the sentence here does not contain such a 「に」I assumed that they are at least related. In any case, I can't figure out in which way "purpose of doing verb..." would fit here...

Therefore my question is what exactly does this "purpose" mean in sentences like that.

(My assumption is that "purpose" is something I usually assume with something "positive"; however in the explanation it could have the meaning of 「ため」)

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23789/%e3%81%a6-versus-combining-form-for-joining-clauses

Comment: Thank you, I might as well delete my question now...